# Google Mobile Vision ocrlib.so file downloading error

Tags: android, google-play-services, ocr, text-recognition

I am using  Google Mobile Vision TextRecogniser API in my application to read text from a captured image. But I am getting below error every time.

````
I/Vision: Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: false
I/Vision: Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text:0
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:2702
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 2702
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr:0```

This vision message is what causing the problem:

**E/Vision:Request download for engine ocr is a no-op because rate limiting**
````

Comment: paste your dependencies here

Comment: app level dependency:

`{  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2'
    qaImplementation files('libs/ocrlibrary-release-qa.aar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

libs/ocrlibrary-release-qa.aar level dependency:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to resolve this issue by factory resetting the device. I was using the knox profile so first i unassigned the existing knox profile and then factory reset the device and it was workign fine. Cheers!

Comment: is there any way to make it work with Samsung Knox? I have the same issue, but I have to scan the qrcode under the samsung knox profile